# Wordpress json rest api displaying 10 categories only

Tags: api

Wordpress rest api for categories is displaying 10 categories only. how can i get all list of categories in the api.
please help me out of this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [REST API Pagination](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/): by default you'll get a page of 10 results and two headers in the results, X-WP-Total and X-WP-TotalPages, to tell you how many pages of results there are.

You can request more results in one go by adding `?per_page=100` to the request, i.e.

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?per_page=100
```

100 is the maximum you can request at once. You should then check the `X-WP-TotalPages` header in the response and if it's more than 1 you need to repeat for further pages of results, i.e.

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?per_page=100&page=2
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?per_page=100&page=3
```

etc. as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, Its working

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default 100 post limit. In this example, the override is for 200 posts

```
function rest_api_override_per_page( $params ) {
  if ( isset( $params ) AND isset( $params[ 'per_page' ] ) ) {
    $params[ 'per_page' ] = array( 200 );
  }
  return $params;
}
add_action( 'rest_api_collection_params', 'rest_api_override_per_page' );
```